# Best/most clean way to inject dependencies into Servlets without any frameworks

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

What is the best way to inject dependencies into Servlets when you don't want to use any sort of DI frameworks? Shall I put them into the `ServletContext` in a `ServletContextListener`?

Comment: Not even the DI framework that is part of JavaEE 6?

Comment: @skaffman I only need to inject 2-3 dependencies. I'm unsure if the added complexity is worth the effort.

Comment: @skaffman: You probably don't want to use a DI framework if you're building a simple servlet-based library or plugin. Not that this is the case, but just pointing out other reasons.

Comment: @skaffman: Jetty is far from Java EE 6.

Comment: What kind of dependencies? Does Jetty support JNDI? If so, just `@Resource` ought to be enough.

Comment: @BalusC I use @Resource for the DataSource, which works fine but I also need inject classes of my own, which isn't possible in Jetty (AFAIK).

Comment: You could just define those classes in JNDI as well, exactly the same way as you did for `DataSource`.

Comment: @BalusC Could you show a link/example of how to do this? I haven't found anything on the web.

Comment: I don't do Jetty, so I can't go in detail. For Tomcat/Glassfish/JBoss/etc, I'd just say, the same way as you did for `DataSource`. Just define it in JNDI and give it a JNDI name. It just becomes an applicationwide instance which is available by `@Resource`. Or is it really that tightcoupled/specific in Jetty? Setting as a `ServletContext` attribute is then your best resort. That's already been answered. Here's another example from my hand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491596/get-database-connection-from-a-connection-pool/4492111#4492111

Comment: @BalusC I'll just try that out. Would be great if that would work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You could initialize them in a `ServletContextListener` (if you need them pre-initialized) and then put them into the `ServletContext` for all your servlets to access.

It's probably best to store the objects by their class name so retrieval is type-safe.

```
Foo foo = servletContext.getAttribute(Foo.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

To inject something in servlets, you need to get the servlet instances in another class. And you can't do that, because the `getServlet(name)` method is deprecated (and not working).

So each servlet will have to register itself manually in the context. In the `init()` method of each servlet you can add itself to a collection in the servlet context:

```
((List<HttpServlet>) servletContext.getAttribute("servlets")).add(this);
```

Then, in a `ServletContextListener` you can loop all registered servlets and invoke some setters, or user reflection, to externally set the dependencies.

But..that seems too complicates, so you might stick with the `new` operator here and there.