# How to configure Eclipse with Tomcat and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to get rows from a MySQL table with JSP in Eclipse. My Tomcat server is started, jConnector is in JRE Library and my code is:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnection {
    public Connection getDBConnection() throws Exception{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","myuname","mypass");
        return conn;
    }
}
```

JSP is :

```
<jsp:useBean id="dbConn" scope="request" class="dbConn.DBConnection"/>
<%
  Connection conn=dbConn.getDBConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from user");
%>
<html>
...
<body>
<%while (rs.next()){ %>
<h1><%=rs.getString(2) %></h1>
<%} %>
</body>
</html>
<%
  if(conn!=null)
    conn.close();
%>
```

And final result is

> error: root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 2):

> *jConnector is in JRE Library*

This is not correct. You should drop the JAR file in web project's `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. That should be basically all you need to do. Everything in this folder ends up in webapp's runtime classpath. If you have also fiddled around in project's *Build Path* properties, then I recommend to undo that all. It would otherwise possibly break or confuse something else now or in the future.

#### See also:

- [Class not found loading JDBC org.postgresql.Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904756/class-not-found-loading-jdbc-org-postgresql-driver)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: writing Java code in a JSP file is strongly discouraged since a decade. I recommend to write Java code in normal Java classes and learn about servlets to control the HTTP requests.

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Show JDBC ResultSet in HTML in JSP page using MVC and DAO pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003142/jsp-using-mvc-and-jdbc)