# Do you need to close the connection you get from jdbc connection pool?

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling

Suppose I have the following code

```
DataSource source = (DataSource) (new InitialContext()).lookup("jdbc/myName"); 
Connection connnection = source.getConnection() 

//use the connection to do some database operations...
```

at the end, should I still call 
`connection.close()` to release the resource?

If the connection is from a connection pool, if I don't do anything, the connection should be automatically returned to the pool, right?

On the other hand, if I close it, is there gonna be any adverse effect on the connection pool (ie, after several calls, there won't be any connection left in the pool?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and check [Closing JDBC Connections in Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938517/closing-jdbc-connections-in-pool) and [JDBC Connection Pooling Best Practices](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be closing the connection, if only for quick recovery by the pool.

This article http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html advises placement of a .close() call in a finally block.