# Singleton in JSP, how to properly tidy up on close?

Tags: java, jsp, destructor

I am just getting started with jsp and my question is this - when I have a singleton class, how do I tidy up after it?

In particular:

```
public class DBConnection {
  private static Connection connection = null;
  private static Statement statement = null;

  public static ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
    if (connection == null) { /*initConnection*/ }
    if (statement == null) { /*initStatement*/ }

    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

Now, I use this class in several pages to get results from jdbc. However, I need to eventually call `statement.close();` and `connection.close();` - when should I call those?

I am using singleton, because it felt wrong to call for connection to a database over and over whenever I needed to make a query.

Comment: close it after your retrieve needed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Connection` must be closed **always**, and after you have executed all your database statements for the desired operations. Two examples:

Case 1: You must show a list of products to user filtered by criteria from database. Solution: get a connection, retrieve a list of products using the filter criteria, close the connection.

Case 2: The client selects some of these products and updates the minimum stock to get an alert and restock them. Solution: get a connection, update all the products, close the connection.

Based on these cases, we can learn lot of things:

- You can execute more than a single statement while having/maintaining a single connection open.
- The connection should live only in the block where it is used. It should not live before or after that.
- Both cases can happen at the same time since they are in a multi threaded environment. So, a single database connection **must not** be available to be used by two threads **at the same time**, in order to avoid result problems. For example, user A searches the products that are in category Foo and user B searches the products that are in category Bar, you don't want to show the products in category Bar to user A.
- From last sentence, each database operation ((or group of similar operations like Case 2) should be handled in an *atomic* operation. To assure this, the connection **must not** be stored in a singleton object, instead it must be live only in the method being used.

In consequence:

- **Do not** declare the `Connection` nor the `Statement` nor the `ResultSet` nor other JDBC resource as `static`. It will simply **fail**. Instead, declare only the `Connection` as field of your `DBConnection` class. Let each method decide to handle each `Statement` (or `PreparedStatement`) and `ResultSet` and specific JDBC resources.
- Since you **must** close the connection after its usage, then add two more methods: `void open()` and `void close()`. These methods will handle the database connection retrieval and closing that connection.
- Additional, since the `DBConnection` looks like a wrapper class for `Connection` class and database connection operations, I would recommend to have at least three more methods: `void setAutoCommit(boolean autoCommit)`, `void commit()` and `void rollback()`. These methods will be plain wrappers for [`Connection#setAutoCommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean))  [`Connection#close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#commit()) and [`Connection#rollback`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#rollback()) respectively.

Then you can use the class in this way:

```
public List<Product> getProducts(String categoryName) {
    String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM Product WHERE categoryName = ?";
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    DBConnection dbConnection = new DBConnection();
    try {
        dbConnection.open();
        ResultSet resultSet = dbConnection.executeSelect(sql, categoryName); //execute select and apply parameters
        //fill productList...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //always handle your exceptions
        ...
    } finally {
        //don't forget to also close other resources here like ResultSet...
        //always close the connection
        dbConnection.close();
    }
}
```

Note that in this example the `PreparedStatement` is not in the `getProducts` method, it will be a local variable of the `executeSelect` method.

Additional notes:

- When working in an application server, you **should not** open connections naively e.g. using `Class.forName("...")`, instead use a database connection pool. You can roll on some database connection pooling libraries like C3P0 as explained here: [How to establish a connection pool in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2835090/1065197). Or configure one in your application server, as I explain here: [Is it a good idea to put jdbc connection code in servlet class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15981244/1065197)
- If this is for learning purposes, then roll on your own classes to handle the communication with your database. In real world applications, this is not recommended (doesn't mean you should not do it). Instead, use a database connectivity framework like ORMs e.g. [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) (Java official ORM framework) or [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/); there are no ORM frameworks that handles database communication like [Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) and [MyBatis](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/). The choice is yours.

More info:

- [Should a database connection stay open all the time or only be opened when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18962852/1065197)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/1065197). Not directly related to your question, but it will help you understand why to not maintain state in resources that are used in multithreaded environments.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough explanation. One question though. Is it reasonable to have a static class providing methods such as `public static Flight getFlightByID(int flightID);` ? This method would instantiate DBConnection, connect, do its queries, and then close, as you suggested. The said static class does not have any member variables, it only provides its methods.

Comment: @MartinMelka no, it is not. In fact, you should avoid using singletons at all.

Answer (score 1):

Define connection resource in mywebapp/META-INF/context.xml file

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    maxActive="10" maxIdle="2" maxWait="20000" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
    username="myuser" password="mypwd" 
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

Create DB.java helper class to minimize code in other parts of app

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

public class DB {

public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
    try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
        return ds.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        SQLException sqex = new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
        sqex.initCause(ex);
        throw sqex;
    }
}

public static void close(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt, Connection conn) {
       if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
       if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
       if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}

public static void close(ResultSet rs, boolean closeStmtAndConn) {
       if (rs==null) return;
       try {
          Statement stmt = rs.getStatement();
          close(rs, stmt, stmt!=null ? stmt.getConnection() : null);
       } catch (Exception ex) { }
}

}
```

And somewhere in your app DAO code use DB helper.

```
public List<MyBean> getBeans() throws SQLException {
    List<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try {
        Connection con = DB.createConnection();
        String sql = "Select * from beantable where typeid=?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setInt(1, 101);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()
            list.add( createBean(rs) );
    } finally {
        DB.close(rs, true); // or DB.close(rs, stmt, conn);
    }
    return list;
}

private MyBean createBean(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    MyBean bean = new MyBean();
    bean.setId( rs.getLong("id") );
    bean.setName( rs.getString("name" );
    bean.setTypeId( rs.getInt("typeid") );
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add two methods to the class:

```
public static void open() throws SomeException;
public static void close() throws SomeException;
```

then your calling code looks something like this{

```
try {
    DBConnection.open();
    ... code to use the connection one or more times ...
} finally {
    DBConnection.close();
}
```

Wrap all your database calls inside that and it will take care of closing whether there is an exception thrown or not.

Of course, this isn't much different than having a regular class, which I might recommend:

```
try {
    DBConnection conn = new DBConnection();
    conn.open();

    ... all the code to use the database (but you pass 'conn' around) ...

} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

And you might want to look at the  `java.lang.AutoCloseable` and  `java.io.Closeable` to see if that helps you.

**2**

If you are keeping it open across page loads, there isn't any place to put the `try ... finally` stuff so you can open it and close it when the servlet closes or the server closes or something like that.

If you are going to leave it open, you need to make sure and add code to verify it doesn't close when you aren't looking. A short network glitch, for example, could close it down. In that case, you need to reopen it when it gets closed. Otherwise, all database access from that point will fail.

You might want to look into the concept of a DataBase Pool. Apache has one -- DBCP. Tomcat has its own that's quite good. Other containers, like JBOSS, WebSphere, WebLogic all have them. There's a couple that can be used with the Spring Framework. What it does is manage one or more database connections. Your code asks it for one and it returns an open one, unless none is available and then it opens one and returns it. You call `close` when your code gets through with it but it doesn't really close the connection, it just returns it to the pool.

You can usually configure the pool to check for shut down connections and reopen if needed.

Comment: That is true, if it was used only in the said block. However, I have several pages, from which I do my queries through the same DBConnection that remains opened. I don't think it is good to connect and disconnect to the database on *each* page load. Or is it?

Comment: There's a huge problem here that is handling the connection state in a singleton. This is plain wrong =\

Comment: Tomcat or any j2ee provides connection pool so calling conn.close() does not actually close it but puts back to a pool for reuse. Pool handles broken connections, limit max open connection etc.. boiler stuff. Its very lightweight using conns from the pool. And no two threads should access same connection instance at the same time, it will happen if you use static singletons.

Comment: @Whome even when using a database connection pool, you must call `Connection#cllose` to return the connection to the pool and let it handle the connection behavior. When you don't call this method, the connection is still open and the application will have performance leaks.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Right. You DO have to close. But you can call close after each small access to the database and the pool keeps things open to the database server over the long term.

Comment: @LeeMeador leave that work and problems to the connection pool, after all, that's what it was made for.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I much prefer your solution to the problem but its not what the OP asked. What was asked was how to close connections when using a static class. Neither of us really answered that question though I tried to show how it could be done in my first section. Solutions to this problem have come a long way since the 1900s but newcomers haven't seen how poor the older solutions are. I stand by my main point about making sure to close what you open and the secondary point about using a pool.

Comment: @LeeMeador the solution is: stop having the connection in a static class for several reasons and start using it locally. After doing this, you can close the connection after using it. All this is covered in my answer, but maybe it is not clear.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I guess we disagree on the "how" of answering this question which was "when I have a singleton class, how do I tidy up after it?" We do not disagree on how best to do database access in this situation.

Comment: The question is how to close connections in a singleton class in a multithreaded environment, from the title: *Singleton In JSP*, and web applications are by default multithreaded. The first step to solve this **in these environments** is to understand why is **bad** to store the connection in a singleton object. For example, two requests fire at the same time and try to execute different `SELECT` statements, but one of them finishes early than the other; since they're using the same `Connection` object, then the one that finished first would close it and the other operation will break.

Comment: After realizing this, the solution pops up immediately: **do not use a singleton object for `Connection` in multithreaded environments**.