# Tomcat JDBC connection pool (releasing connection)

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Referring to [Tomcat JBDC connection pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html), I see in the standalone java example given there, one gets the connection using `datasource.getConnection()`which is cool. But in the finally block, it says `con.close()`.

Question: When I implement this, it seems obvious that the `con` I get from datasource will be closed every time in the finally. When this is closed, will the connection pooling mechanism acquire a new connection and adds it to the pool?

I presume there should be a method call like `releaseConnection()` that will let the pool take its own decision whether to close it or let it be open for some other use.

I've also tried doing this `ConnectionPool aPool = datasource.createPool();`
But I see there is nothing like release connection on this `aPool`.

I think I'm missing something here?
Appreciate your help.

Code snippet from [Tomcat JBDC connection pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html):

```
            DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
            datasource.setPoolProperties(p); 

            Connection con = null;
            try {
              con = datasource.getConnection();
              Statement st = con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user");
              int cnt = 1;
              while (rs.next()) {
                  System.out.println((cnt++)+". Host:" +rs.getString("Host")+
                    " User:"+rs.getString("User")+" Password:"+rs.getString("Password"));
              }
              rs.close();
              st.close();
            } finally {
              if (con!=null) try {con.close();}catch (Exception ignore) {}
            }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you call the close() on a method obtained by the pool it is up to the pool what to do inside this method call. It does not neccessarily have to close the pooled database connection - it may do some cleanup and then add the connetion back to the pool.

This is already answered in [Closing JDBC Connections in Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938517/closing-jdbc-connections-in-pool)

Comment: Keep "MaxIdle" setting of DataSource high enough to get those connections not being closed. Setting it to 0 will shutdown any closed connection, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

OK, my bad, that I did not see the implementation of `DataSource`.
It extends `DataSourceProxy` that internally creates a pool before returning a `Connection`based on the `PoolProperties`

I understand, its upto this DataSource to handle the connections, even though I close the `con` in finally, DataSource may take necessary action.

Do add a comment/reply if anybody thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

That example only shows `how to create and use a data source`. For connection pool on Tomcat you may configure [`JNDI`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).

```
// Sample
public static Connection getConnectionFromPool() {
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
    return ds.getConnection();
    ...
```

Quote from [How connection pooling works in Java and JDBC](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=203):

> A connection pool operates by performing the work of creating
>   connections ahead of time, In the case of a JDBC connection pool, a
>   pool of Connection objects is created at the time the application
>   server (or some other server) starts. These objects are then managed
>   by a pool manager that disperses connections as they are requested by
>   clients and returns them to the pool when it determines the client is
>   finished with the Connection object. A great deal of housekeeping is
>   involved in managing these connections.
>
> When the connection pool server starts, it creates a predetermined
>   number of Connection objects. A client application would then perform
>   a JNDI lookup to retrieve a reference to a DataSource object that
>   implements the ConnectionPoolDataSource interface. The client
>   application would not need make any special provisions to use the
>   pooled data source; the code would be no different from code written
>   for a nonpooled DataSource.