# How to release connection from JDBC connection pool in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a JDBC Connection pool in Tomcat and my max= 5 connections. now when I get 6 connections then i get an error.

How can I release an old connection to put into the connection pool so that I can get the 6th connection?

Which command do I have to use in java to release a connection?

Comment: Show us the code that uses a connection from the pool.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tomcat JDBC connection pool (releasing connection)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413471/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-releasing-connection)

Comment: Usually it's `connection.close()` when no longer needed (along with resultSet, preparedStatement, and so on), but without any code sample as @LutzHorn suggested, we have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

For datasources that comply with the JDBC specification the way to return connections to the connection pool is to call `close()`.

The JDBC specification mandates that connections obtained from a pool should behave no different (from the perspective of the user of that connection) as a non-pooled connection; that includes having to call `close()` when you are done with the connection. To this end a connection pool usually wraps or proxies a connection so that it can return the connection to the pool (+ additional cleanup like closing statement and resultset (proxies)) when `close()`.