# Inserting preparedstatement to database - PSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

This seems like a really simple problem, but I cannot figure out what my problem is. I have a method addTask  which adds some info to our database as seen in this code:

```
public static boolean addTask(String name, String question, int accuracy, int type){
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
      sql.append("INSERT INTO tasks (name, question, type, accuracy) ");
      sql.append("VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
      try {
        Connection c = DbAdaptor.connect();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = c.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        preparedStatement.setString(1, name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, question);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, type);
        preparedStatement.setInt(4, accuracy);
        preparedStatement.execute();
        preparedStatement.close();
        c.close();
            return true;
      }       
      catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          return false;
      }
}
```

my problem is that preparedStatement.execute() always returns false, indicating the information hasnt been added to the database. I can run psql and this confirms that nothing has been written to the db. The connection definitely connects to the correct database (i put in some other printlns etc. to check this). I am trying to insert into a newly initialised table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  submitter INTEGER REFERENCES accounts (id),
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  question VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  accuracy INTEGER NOT NULL,
  type INTEGER REFERENCES types (id),
  ex_time TIMESTAMP,
  date_created TIMESTAMP
);
```

code for DbAdaptor.connect():

```
public static Connection connect(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("user", USER);
      properties.setProperty("password", PASSWORD);
    try {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, properties);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

where `USER` and `PASSWORD` are static fields in the class

Comment: A side note: You are not closing the opened resources (statement and connection).

Comment: Can you share the `DbAdaptor.connect()` method? Since you are saying nothing is written into the database, check whether the code is running under a transaction? Check the `setAutoCommit()` value of the connection object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit(boolean)

Comment: @ArunPJohny
I've put up the `DbAdaptor.connect()` code, AutoCommit should be enabled, I haven't done anything to change it. I've updated the above code to include closing of resources too, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: In your postgres database, whether you have multiple schemas?

Comment: Another note: Why the exceptions are killed within the `connect()` method? You are suppose to propagate the exception to the caller, so that the caller will know that there was an error while creating the connection. Your `addTask()` method is a good candidate for `NullPointerException` if an exception occurs while creating the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood the return value of [`PreparedStatement#execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29).

Please carefully read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute%28%29):

> #### Returns:
>
> `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

It thus returns — as fully expected — `false` on an `INSERT` query. It returns only `true` on a `SELECT` query (for which you'd however usually like to use [`executeQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) instead which returns directly a `ResultSet`).

If you're interested in the affected rows, rather use [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) instead. It returns an `int` as per [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29):

> #### Returns:
>
> either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

A return value of 1 or greater would then indicate a successful insert.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: your code is leaking DB resources. Please carefully read [How often should Connection, Statement and ResultSet be closed in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602772/how-often-should-statement-and-resultset-objects-be-closed-in-jdbc)

Comment: thanks for the advice about closing, I've modified my code to close the resources once I've finished. The return value was an error I've just inserted which I've now changed back to just return true; all this can be seenin my updated code. I still have the problem of not actually updating the db though.

Comment: As to the closing, that should happen in `finally`. Right now they still risk to leak away when an exception is thrown during executing the SQL query. As to the actual insert, well that can be caused by the connection not being committed (the close implicitly does that) or just by looking in the wrong DB or table or an outdated view.

Comment: What's weird is that it doesn't seem to be wrong db/table or anything like that, if add in

    `Statement stat = c.createStatement();
    s.execute("SELECT id, name FROM tasks");`

the result set of s contains the dummy values I initialise tasks with (definitely no naming conflicts within the table either)