# How to reuse database connection in JSP/Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

Currently I'm creating the DB connection again and again in every JSP/Servlet. I would like to reuse my DB connection in my JSP/Servlet project. How can I achieve this?

Comment: JEE has native support for connection pools. What's your application server?

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313197/jdbc-mysql-connection-pooling-practices

Comment: @JBNizet Am using tomcat v7.0

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "correct" way to do this is to make use of [connection pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool).  That way the overhead of creating / closing connections is reduced.

Apart from that there's is nothing wrong with the way you are doing things.  Maintaining open connections for too long is generally not a good idea.

To make this less hassle - you can create a utility class which returns a connection from the pool and likewise has a method for returning the connection to the pool.