# DataTable - InCell Editing--- how to update database with edited values

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, primefaces

```
 I have a managed bean called registerBean.

        private List<registerBean> std;

        public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
            registerBean ul = (registerBean) event.getObject();
            Connection con = null;
            PreparedStatement stat = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "root", "");
                stat = con.prepareStatement("update regtbl set fname=? where rno=?");
                stat.setString(1, ul.fname);
                stat.setInt(3, ul.rno);
                stat.executeUpdate();
                con.commit();
                stat.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    This is my Facelets page

    std.xhtml

    <!-- language: xhtml -->

        <p:dataTable  value="#{registerBean.list}"  var="rb"  rows="10" paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate=" {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}  {NextPageLink}  {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,15,20" rowKey="#{rb.fname}" selectionMode="single"
            selection="#{registerBean.selectedStudent}"
            scrollable="true" resizableColumns="true"  editable="true" >
            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{registerBean.onEdit}"
                update=":form:messages" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{registerBean.onCancel}"
                update=":form:messages" />
            <p:column headerText="Roll No" filterBy="#{rb.rno}" sortBy="#{rb.rno}" width="124">
                <h:outputText value="#{rb.rno}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="First Name" filterBy="#{rb.fname}" sortBy="#{rb.fname}" width="124">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{rb.fname}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <h:inputText value="#{rb.fname}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
            <!-- more columns... -->
        </p:dataTable>
```

> Am I going wrong some where here ..... this method is called to
>   save the edited rows of datatable.... but database records are not
>   getting updated. When I edit a particular row in datatable and click
>   on right mark to save the changes onEdit method is being called which
>   is inside bean. The issue is database value are remaining the same not
>   getting updated   list is of type registerBean. In registerBean I am
>   performing other operations like Inserting (working fine ), getting
>   values from database that are displayed in datatable ... facing
>   problem in row editing.
>
> ```
> Thanks in Advance
>
> Note: Check [this link][1]. My table is similar to this but i am using database.
>
> [1]: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf
> ```

Comment: please post your backing bean code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the [missing `finally` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313197/jdbc-mysql-connection-pooling-practices/2313262#2313262), the unnecessarily repeated `Class#forName()` call and the [completely unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstance/2093236#2093236) `newInstance()` call on it, [tight-coupling](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) data access code in a controller class, not using a fast connection pool, all which are unrelated to the concrete problem, the code posted so far looks okay.

Only, you're setting the `rno` value as 3rd parameter while you've only 2 in your prepared SQL string.

```
    stat = con.prepareStatement("update regtbl set fname=? where rno=?");
    stat.setString(1, ul.fname);
    stat.setInt(3, ul.rno);
```

I'm not sure if this is careless oversimplification or if you have really read the server logs for any indication of the `e.printStackTrace()`, but this is not right. Make sure that the `ul.rno` is set on parameter index 2. I'd also rather fix that silly `e.printStackTrace()` which causes the code to **continue** to run which you obviously don't want to happen.

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new FacesException(e);
}
```

If the SQL was indeed right after all and you indeed don't get an exception, then apparently there's simply no row which matches the `WHERE` clause. The [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) returns an `int` representing the affected rows. I suggest to get hold of it and verify if there was really an update:

```
int affectedRows = stat.executeUpdate();

if (affectedRows == 0) {
    // No rows affected!
}
```

Also check what value of `ul.rno` you've set it with.

---

**Update** *finally* you took the little effort to read the server logs for any evidence of the exception. You should understand that exceptions are **very important** to learn about as they basically are the whole answer to your concrete problem. The one which you retrieved is basically telling that in the following piece of code

```
public String getBdate() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    bdate = sdf.format(dob);
    return bdate;
}
```

the variable `dob` is `null`. You should be doing a nullcheck:

```
public String getBdate() { 
    if (dob != null) {
        bdate = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT).format(dob);
    }

    return bdate;
}
```

Comment: BalusC !!! go through this link http://www.coderanch.com/t/593245/JSF/java/Ajax-Validations-not-working-after. Thanks in Advance