# Firebird query is crashing with org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544364. request synchronization error

Tags: java, spring, firebird, jdbctemplate, firebird2.1

I am using JdbcTemplate.queryForInt to insert a Row into the DB, and then get the ID back.

The Query is `"INSERT INTO metadocs(NAME) values (?) RETURNING METADOCID"`. If I run the statement in Flamerobin, it works fine.

However, if I run it from Java, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO metadocs(NAME) values (?) RETURNING METADOCID]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [335544364]; GDS Exception. 335544364. request synchronization error; nested exception is org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544364. request synchronization error

Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544364. request synchronization error
```

Does anyone have an idea what this could be caused by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Oracle, I'm not sure that the [Jaybird JDBC driver](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=doc) supports the `RETURNING` syntax. Alternatively, you might look at the [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) method , discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/jdbc-how-can-we-get-inserted-record-id-in-java/1915197#1915197).

Comment: I verified that firebird supports the "RETURNING"-clause - but the JDBC driver does not :-(

Comment: I appreciate the feed back. Any luck with `getGeneratedKeys()`?