# PLSQL JDBC: How to get last row ID?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

What's PLSQL (Oracle) equivalent of this SQL server snippet?

```
BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO mytable(content) VALUES ("test") -- assume there's an ID column that is autoincrement
SELECT @@IDENTITY
COMMIT TRAN
```

In C#, you can call myCommand.ExecuteScalar() to retrieve the ID of the new row.

How can I insert a new row in Oracle, and have JDBC get a copy of the new id?

**EDIT:**
BalusC provided a very good starting point. For some reason JDBC doesn't like named parameter binding. This gives "Incorrectly set or registered parameters" SQLException. Why is this happening?

```
        OracleConnection conn = getAppConnection();
        String q = "BEGIN INSERT INTO tb (id) values (claim_seq.nextval) returning id into :newId; end;" ;
        CallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall(q);
        cs.registerOutParameter("newId", OracleTypes.NUMBER);
        cs.execute();
        int newId = cs.getInt("newId");
```

Comment: Select the max of the id field + 1 ?

Comment: @Aren - `max(n)+1` doesn't scale and doesn't work in a multi-user environment.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Normally* you would use [`Statement#getGeneratedKeys()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) for this (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/jdbc-how-can-we-get-inserted-record-id-in-java/1915197#1915197) for an example), but this is as far (still) not supported by the Oracle JDBC driver.

Your best bet is to *either* make use of [`CallableStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) with a `RETURNING` clause:

```
String sql = "BEGIN INSERT INTO mytable(id, content) VALUES (seq_mytable.NEXTVAL(), ?) RETURNING id INTO ?; END;";

Connection connection = null;
CallableStatement statement = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
    statement.setString(1, "test");
    statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.NUMERIC);
    statement.execute();
    int id = statement.getInt(2);
    // ...
```

*Or* fire `SELECT sequencename.CURRVAL` after `INSERT` in the same transaction:

```
String sql_insert = "INSERT INTO mytable(content) VALUES (?)";
String sql_currval = "SELECT seq_mytable.CURRVAL FROM dual";

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
Statement currvalStatement = null;
ResultSet currvalResultSet = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql_insert);
    statement.setString(1, "test");
    statement.executeUpdate();
    currvalStatement = connection.createStatement();
    currvalResultSet = currvalStatement.executeQuery(sql_currval);
    if (currvalResultSet.next()) {
        int id = currvalResultSet.getInt(1);
    }
    connection.commit();
    // ...
```

Comment: Do you mean "SELECT seq_mytable.CURRVAL from dual" instead of "SELECT CURRVAL(seq_mytable)"?

Comment: @Patrick: Oh drat, I had PostgreSQL SQL syntax in mind, I'll update (previously, PostgreSQL used to have the same problem of not supporting [`Statement#getGeneratedKeys()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/jdbc-how-can-we-get-inserted-record-id-in-java/1915197#1915197) so that the same "workaround" was necessary, but since about a year ago they finally fixed their JDBC driver to support it).

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for the help. Can you take a look at my edit see if you can solve that other mystery?

Comment: You need to specify the placeholder index, not the column name. Replace `"newId"` by `2` in `registerOutParameter()`.

Comment: In practice, I have a long insert statement with 15-some parameters, which I prefer having named binding if I could. JDBC will complain about having mixed binding if I use question mark. Do I must go with ordinal binding when out-parameter is used?

Comment: For named binding, use an ORM like Hibernate/JPA. Basic JDBC doesn't support it.

Comment: I believe there is nothing incorrect with the JDBC specification from Oracle Driver's perspective. The prepareStatement call needs to be told to return auto-generated keys like this. conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

Comment: @Subramanian: So it has changed recently? So the example in the linked answer works for Oracle now? Note that both answers are posted 2 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Oracle's [**returning**](http://www.lattimore.id.au/2006/04/06/oracle-returning-clause/) clause.

```
insert into mytable(content) values ('test') returning your_id into :var;
```

Check out [this link](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1702717) for a code sample. You need Oracle 10g or later, and a new version of JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getGeneratedKeys(), By explicitly selecting key field.
Here is a snippet:

```
    // change the string to your connection string
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("connection string");

    // assume that the field "id" is PK, and PK-trigger exists 
    String sql = "insert into my_table(id) values (default)";
    // you can select key field by field index
    int[] colIdxes = { 1 };
    // or by field name
    String[] colNames = { "id" };

    // Java 1.7 syntax; try-finally for older versions
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, colNames))
    {
        // note: oracle JDBC driver do not support auto-generated key feature with batch update
        //          // insert 5 rows
        //          for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        //          {
        //              preparedStatement.addBatch();
        //          }
        //          
        //          int[] batch = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        // get generated keys
        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys())
        {
            while (resultSet.next())
            {
                // assume that the key's type is BIGINT
                long id = resultSet.getLong(1);
                assertTrue(id != 0);

                System.out.println(id);
            }
        }
    }
```

refer for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17657/jdbcvers.htm#CHDEGDHJ

Comment: This works as long as the insert statement has up to 7 parameters, when there are more than 7 parameters an ArrayIndexOutofBound exception is thrown. Looks like a fault with the oracle jdbc driver. #Oracle_11g_R2. Answer from BalusC is better because of this reason.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use `spring-jdbc` for database you can consider neat wrappers from [morejdbc](https://github.com/seregamorph/morejdbc), it will look like this:

```java
import static org.morejdbc.SqlTypes.BIGINT;
import static org.morejdbc.JdbcCall.callSql;
import static org.morejdbc.*;
...

Out<Long> idOut = Out.of(BIGINT);
jdbcTemplate.execute(callSql("BEGIN INSERT INTO mytable(id, content) VALUES (seq_mytable.NEXTVAL(), ?) "
        + "RETURNING id INTO ?; END;")
        .in(content)
        .out(BIGINT, idOut));
System.out.println("Id is " + idOut.get());
```

If you have a pojo like

```java
@lombok.Data
public class Entity {
    private long id;
    private String content;
}
```

it can be even more laconic:

```
Entity entity = ;

jdbcTemplate.execute(callSql("BEGIN INSERT INTO mytable(id, content) VALUES (seq_mytable.NEXTVAL(), ?) "
        + "RETURNING id INTO ?; END;")
        .in(entity.getContent())
        .out(BIGINT, entity::setId));
System.out.println("Id is " + entity.get());
```