# Beginner JDBC Result Set questions

Tags: java, jdbc

New to using JDBC and I was wondering if all operations produce a result set. For example I am making statements to insert/update to a database via:

```
StringBuffer query1 = new StringBuffer("UPDATE table SET col1 = value, WHERE some_col = some_val");
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatment(query1.toString());
ResultSet rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
```

So would this snippet, when executed just act out the appropriate update and be done? Or would I need to handle the result set in some way in order to complete the operation?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I'm following a template of sorts given to me by my Project Manager. I'm a new grad and new to the company, so I'm trying to stick with their procedures while I learn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using [`PreparedStatement#executeUpdate()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) rather than [`executeQuery()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29). It returns an `int` indicating the amount of affected rows.

```
int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

That said, constructing a SQL string that way is not the normal idiom. You would rather like to use placeholders `?` and use the `PreparedStatement` setters to set the values.

```
String sql = "UPDATE table SET col1 = ? WHERE some_col = ?";
// ...    
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatment(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, col1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, someCol);
int affectedRows = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Basic JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)
- [Using PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. And I am using the PreparedStatement setters in my actual code. I probably should have been more specific in my snippet. Apologies on my part.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to handle the ResultSet - it will be empty anyway, because an update operation shouldn't return results from the database. Usually you would call a different metho on the statement:

```
StringBuffer query1 = new StringBuffer("UPDATE table SET col1 = value, WHERE some_col = some_val");
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatment(query1.toString());
int rowCount = pstmt1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Actually there are situations where an UPDATE _can_ return a ResultSet and in that case execute() should be used together with getResultSet()

Comment: @a_horse: That depends on the SQL string and even then, you'd rather like to use `CallableStatement` instead. I'll roughly guess that you're talking about returning insert ID, for that JDBC offers the `getGeneratedKeys()` method which can be used afterwards (you're only dependent on the JDBC driver if it's supported; as of now most of them supports it, only Oracle's one doesn't (yet?)). See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552260/plsql-jdbc-how-to-get-last-row-id).

Comment: I'm not talking about getGeneratedKeys(). Several DBMS support the "RETURNING" clause (for UPDATE, DELETE and INSERT statements). For an UPDATE statement, execute() would then return a result set with all modified rows. A DELETE statement would return a result set that contains all deleted rows.

Comment: @a_horse: `CallableStatement` thus. See also the link.

Comment: Seems to depend on the JDBC driver and the DBMS. 
I can run "DELETE FROM emp WHERE id > 42 RETURNING *" (in PostgreSQL). When run through execute(), getResultSet() will then return a result set with all deleted rows. No need for a CallableStatement ;)

Answer (score 0):

tthere is another method for such statements:
`s.execute("..");`