# How to get the auto incremented PK from Oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, sequence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PLSQL JDBC: How to get last row ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552260/plsql-jdbc-how-to-get-last-row-id)

I have implemented a trigger and a sequence for auto incrementing PK, I'm using Oracle 10g as database.
Now I want to INSERT something using JAVA, but I need to save the incremented PK in a variable right after the INSERT. I tried this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sometable 
                                                       VALUES(?, ?)", 
                                                      Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
pstmt.setInt(1, 5);
pstmt.setString(2, "Username");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
ResultSet resultSet = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you'll need to execute that statement before trying to get the generated keys.

Comment: Sorry it was mistake, I forgot to write the line in my question here. In my code the statement is already executed and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the possible generated keys that you want to retrieve.

```
PreparedStatement  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql,new String [] {"ID_ORDER"});
```

Note that the column name is case-sensitive. Finally a JDBC 3.0 driver and Oracle 10g R2 or better are required.

You can check if your current installation supports this mechanism by examining the DatabaseMetaData :

```
DatabaseMetaData metaData =  conn.getMetaData();
log("SupportsGetGeneratedKeys?="+metaData.supportsGetGeneratedKeys());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `customer.getID()` a candidate key of the table? If so, you can run a `SELECT` after the `INSERT` to find the value of the generated PK. Alternatively, you can get rid of the trigger, get the next value of the `SEQUENCE` from the DB in Java, and use that as the PK for the `INSERT`. The drawback of this approach is that inserts from other applications will have to do the same too.