# id is not defined at child.eval

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm writing my first Backbone blog app but when i try to add new post it throws an error.

Here is my **app.js** (all of backbone related components are in this file):

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Post,
    url : "/posts"
});

var PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: _.template("<a href='/posts/{{id}}'>{{title}}</a>"),
    events: {
        'click a': 'handleClick'
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"),
            {trigger: true});
    },
    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        return this;
    }
});

var PostsListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<h1>My Blog</h1><a href='/post/new' class='newPost'>New</a> <ul></ul>"),
    events: {
        'click .newPost': 'handleNewClick'
    },
    handleNewClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"),
            {trigger: true});
    },
    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template();
        var ul = this.$el.find("ul");
        this.collection.forEach(function (post) {
            ul.append(new PostListView({
                model: post
            }).render().el);
        });
        return this;
    }
});

var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template($("#postView").html()),
    events: {
        'click a': 'handleClick'
    },
    render: function () {
        var model = this.model.toJSON();
        model.pubDate = new Date(Date.parse(model.pubDate)).toDateString();
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template(model);
        return this;
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"),
            {trigger: true});
        return false;
    }
});

var PostFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    template: _.template($("#postFormView").html()),
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.posts = options.posts;
    },
    events: {
        'click #submitPost': 'createPost',
        'click .back' : 'backButton'
    },
    render: function () {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template();
        return this;
    },
    backButton: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        postRouter.navigate($(e.currentTarget).attr("href"),
            {trigger: true});
        return false;
    },
    createPost: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var postAttrs = {
            content: $("#postText").val(),
            title: $("#postTitle").val(),
            pubDate: new Date(),
        };
        this.posts.create(postAttrs);
        postRouter.navigate("/", { trigger: true });
        return false;
    }
});

var PostRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function (options) {
        this.posts = options.posts;
        this.main  = options.main;
    },
    routes: {
        '': 'index',
        'posts/:id': 'singlePost',
        'post/new': 'newPost'
    },
    index: function () {
        var pv = new PostsListView({ collection: this.posts });
        this.main.html(pv.render().el);
    },
    singlePost: function (id) {
        var post = this.posts.get(id);
        var pv = new PostView({ model: post });
        this.main.html(pv.render().el);
    },
    newPost: function () {
        var pfv = new PostFormView({ posts: this.posts });
        this.main.html(pfv.render().el);
    }
});
```

I also have some view templates in my index file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Simple Blog </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main"></div>
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/template" id="postFormView">
    <a href="/" class="back">All Posts</a><br />
    <input type="text" id="postTitle" placeholder="post title" />
    <br />
    <textarea id="postText"></textarea>
    <br />
    <button id="submitPost"> Post </button>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="postView">
    <a href='/'>All Posts</a>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{pubDate}}</p>
    {{content}}
</script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script>
    var postRouter = new PostRouter({
        posts: new Posts(<%- posts %>),
        main: $("#main")
    });
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Viewing posts and home page works fine but when I try to create a new post I get this error from the dev tools console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
    at child.eval (eval at _.template (http://localhost:3000/underscore.js:1:1), <anonymous>:6:8)
    at child.template (http://localhost:3000/underscore.js:1214:21)
    at child.render (http://localhost:3000/app.js:27:34)
    at http://localhost:3000/app.js:48:16
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://localhost:3000/underscore.js:79:11)
    at child.Collection.(anonymous function) [as forEach] (http://localhost:3000/backbone.js:956:24)
    at child.render (http://localhost:3000/app.js:45:25)
    at child.index (http://localhost:3000/app.js:118:27)
    at Object.callback (http://localhost:3000/backbone.js:1242:30)
```

The server is a simple nodejs server and output for creating a post is something like this:

```
{"result":{"ok":1,"n":1},"ops":[{"content":"kljhlkjh","title":"jkhjklh","pubDate":"2016-10-29T10:21:47.793Z","id":12,"_id":"5814783b732bbe153461eca4"}],"insertedCount":1,"insertedId
s":["5814783b732bbe153461eca4"]}
```

Comment: [Similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40308655/1218980) which could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Where is the error?

First, you need to find what is causing the error, and where does it comes from.

The error comes from the following line inside the `PostListView`'s `render` function:

```
this.el.innerHTML = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
```

And the error is thrown by underscore's template rendering. Which comes down to:

```
template: _.template("<a href='/posts/{{id}}'>{{title}}</a>"),
```

See the `{{id}}`? It's that one that is not defined when the error occurs.

## What *"`{{id}}` not defined"* means?

You're passing `this.model.toJSON()` as the data for the template. So, it means that `this.model`'s `id` attribute is not defined *yet*.

## Why is my model `id` not defined yet?

It's because creating a new model through the [collection's `create` function](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create) is **asynchronous**.

```
this.posts.create(postAttrs);
// the model hasn't received an id from the server yet.
postRouter.navigate("/", { trigger: true });
```

## How to wait after a collection's `create` call?

Backbone offers `success` and `error` callbacks for most (if not all) its asynchronous functions.

> The options hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will both be
>   passed `(collection, response, options)` as arguments.

So, you could change your `createPost` function to the following, adding a `onPostCreated` callback.

```
createPost: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postAttrs = {
        content: $("#postText").val(),
        title: $("#postTitle").val(),
        pubDate: new Date(),
    };
    this.posts.create(postAttrs, {
        context: this,
        success: this.onPostCreated
    });
    return false;
},
onPostCreated: function() {
    // you don't need to use the router, so your views are self-contained
    Backbone.history.navigate("/", { trigger: true });
},
```