# Showing Auto-generated primary key on JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am creating a simple application in JSP- JDBC for inserting and updating details of employees.

The database is in MySql.The primary key in master table is set to auto increment.
Now when i'm inserting a new employee details, I want to show a newly generated Key in a textfield in JSP.

Is there a way for doing it.??

this is the method i've created in DAO class..

```
public int getMaxId()
    {
        int id=0;
        try{
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","root");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select MAX(emp_id) from emp_details");
            id = rs.getInt("emp_id");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return id;

    }
```

But its shows `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'emp_id' not found.`

Comment: You may want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a while, but I think you can make another call to MySQL and get the ID. `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` perhaps?

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Comment: @Brandon  How do I use this query. By 'ResultSet' or another any other class.

Comment: Yes, with ResultSet. getXXXX('LAST_INSERT_ID()') Maybe? I can't remember. You could always alias it. 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS LAST_ID'