# Auto Increment including Year and Month in MySql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table called > Project with an auto increment field for project estimate bid number called `Project_ID`.

This field is auto incremented. I have created it as an 8 digit character field which carries the field rule.

I need it to auto increment as a two number year, two number month, include a hyphen, and then a number starting at *001* for first record in that time period.

> An example for the month of April 2012 would be 1204-001 for the first
>   record, 1204-002 for the 2nd and etc. then when the month of May rolls
>   around the Project_ID would change to 1205-001.

What I’ve been trying to write is as follows, I kept it as a simple default expression with a default value of

```
Cyear(date()) + (month()) + “-“ + “001” .
```

How I have Achieve this?

Comment: Stored procedure, or do the insert in a progamming language like Perl, Java or C#.  At a minimum, you'll need to 1) select max(Project_id), 2) determine if it's the same or a different month/year, 3) get the year and month code, 4) compute the index (-001, -002, etc) and 5) insert the resulting Project_id value (along with the rest of the fields that go with this record).  IMHO...

Comment: Yes there is no in-built mechanism in MySql to allow this. Follow @paulsm4

Comment: Stored function to get next `Project_ID`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can use *BEFORE INSERT* `TRIGGER` on the table you want the column to be incremented.

Here are some steps to create a simple algorithm and put this code inside the trigger:

```
// get current YEAR
SET @cur_Year = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y'));
// get current MONTH
SET @cur_MONTH = CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m'));
// concatenate YEAR and MONTH
SET @Year_Month = CONCAT(@cur_Year, @cur_MONTH);
// get the last value for the current YEAR and MONTH
SET @max_ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) 
                FROM    tableName 
                WHERE   ID LIKE CONCAT(@Year_Month, '-%'));
// get the last three characters from the id, convert in to
// integer and increment by 1
SET @last_ID = CAST(RIGHT(@max_ID, 3) AS SIGNED) + 1;
// pad zero on the left using LPAD and 
// concatenate it with YEAR and MONTH
SET @new_ID =   CONCAT(@Year_Month,'-',LPAD(CAST(@last_ID AS CHAR(3)), 3, '0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO (Project_ID, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), CONCAT('%y%m-', 
    ((  SELECT RIGHT(CONCAT('000', (RIGHT(Project_ID, 3) + 1)), 3) AS number
        FROM table_name
        WHERE LEFT(Project_ID, 5) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%y%m-'))
        ORDER BY Project_ID DESC
        UNION
    (   SELECT '001')
        LIMIT 1))),
'Col1 data', 'Col2 data', 'Col3 data'
```

This *might* look a bit odd, so I'll just explain the flow:

I use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` so that I can check existing data from `table_name` to see if there are any existing cases already. The `WHERE` will find existing cases, and thanks to both `RIGHT` and `LEFT` it isn't too hard to carve out relevant data needed. If no rows are found, `'001'` is used instead, then you simply assign the existing columns as shown.

Comment: Using your answer looks easier than learning a new subject, triggers. But it is beyond human comprehension. Can you parse it so, we noobs can understand. I am looking an answer for my problem YYMM#### on every increment. For instance for the date 30.11.2022, i wish increments will be like 22110001, 22110002 ...  etc. And in case the threshold id (22119999) does exists, i wish it will set the id to next month: 22120001

Comment: I'm gonna be honest with you; this answer is almost 10 years old and I don't remember myself what this is about. Sounds like you want to do `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y%m0000')` and just plus incrementally with `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I found how to fetch new id here. If I update it later on as a second step, I could able bypass this complicated stuff. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely solved it,just take a look..

At first you have to take a sample table where the columns will be same to the columns of your original table except the column `project_id`.

then first insert a row in the original table where the value of column `project_id`=0 and the other columns are null,just insert the first row manually like this.

Then create a trigger on the sample table like the following...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

delimiter ;;

create trigger t after insert on `try`

for each row

begin

declare v int;

declare c int;

set v=(select max(`project_id`) from `original`);

if(v=0)then

insert into `original` set

`project_id`=concat((select concat(right(substring_index((select * from(select curdate()    from `try` limit 1) as a),'-','1'),2),right(substring_index((select * from(select curdate() from `try` limit 1) as a),'-','2'),2)) from `try` limit 1),'-001'),

`project`=new.`project`;

else

set c=(select right((select max(`project_id`) from `original`)as x,3) from `original` limit 1);

insert into `original` set

`project_id`=concat((select concat(right(substring_index((select * from(select curdate() from `try` limit 1) as a),'-','1'),2),right(substring_index((select * from(select curdate() from `try` limit 1) as a),'-','2'),2)) from `try` limit 1),concat('-00',c+1)),

`project`=new.`project`;

delete from `original` limit 1;

end if;

end;;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

In the above trigger my sample table was **`try`(`project` text)** and the original table was **`original`(`project_id` text,`project` text)**.

After creating a trigger like this on the sample table,start inserting rows in the sample table,the rows will automatically inserted in the original table with auto_increment values in the `project_id` column like..1405-001,1405-002,1405-003.... where `14` is `2014` and `05` is `May` and the rest are auto_incremented values which is being incremented using the trigger.

Just follow the above steps, your problem will be surely solved.