# Changing autoincrement field values as per year in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have a field id in my table which is autoincrement field. It starts from 1,2,3,........ Now every year April 1st i need to reset this id. What ever record i enter from April 1st should start again from 1.  It doesnt need to be updated automatically. I can do it manually every year. What are the options available to do the same? Can anyone please suggest a simple way through which i can achieve the same.

```
Table tender

    id (autoincrement)
    tender_id
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: if your **id** column is **primary key** it is not possible to insert duplicate id

Comment: Any solutions for this pls? or i need to change all the old ids and again run the alter table to reset to 1? Is that a solution?

Comment: your read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167587/auto-increment-automatic-reset-for-each-year) or you can create triggers for ever year reset id

Comment: you should remove **id** as **primary key** if you want to achieve your task

Comment: Yeah i got it. In query how will i give a value '1' initially and with each inserts its should add +1, Is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `alter table` to modify the `auto_increment` for table.

```
alter table t1 auto_increment = 1;
```

Comment: Yes i can do that. Got a doubt. Already id has a value 1 of last years. Now if i run this query, will it take again 1 (id 1 is duplicate in this case)?

Comment: How it works means.. Every year from April 1st my quotation number starts from 1. and it goes on. I have given the id as the quot number

Comment: Then how do you handle the same id `1` last year, from point view of business?

Comment: Last year only we started using the s/w. So this is the first year i need to reset the id.