# MySQL user defined function auto increment value using Date

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, auto-increment

I able to obtain the following code to create a function that help generate auto increment values based on date and number of rows enter. However I can't get it to execute in MySQL. I never create a user define function before so please kindly help correct the code. (This code is converted from MSSQL query)

---

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_ComputeColumn (p_id int, p_CreateDate date)
RETURNS char(8) 
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_revtal char(8);
   DECLARE v_NumberOfRowsToday bigint;

-- get the number of rows inserted in the same day before the current row
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_NumberOfRowsToday 
FROM tickreqs
WHERE createdate= p_CreateDate
AND id < p_id;

-- calculate the string to return
SET v_revtal = DATE_FORMAT (p_CreateDate, 12) + RIGHT('0000' + 
CAST(v_NumberOfRowsToday as varchar(1)), 4);
RETURN v_revtal; 

END;
```

---

*The table tickreqs has an id column and createdate column.

Comment: Why not just have an [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) column instead of this?

Comment: I want to have an auto increment that based on date. like 20170001, 20180001. AUTO_INCREMENT would keep increment all the way, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-increment - automatic reset for each year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167587/auto-increment-automatic-reset-for-each-year)

Comment: Yes it's sort of the same but please help me get the code right, I keep getting incorrect syntax. I have table tickreqs with id as A.I PK, codeyear that store current year and requestcode that would store auto increment code like: 20171, 20172 ... Here is my code `CREATE TRIGGER GenRequestCode BEFORE INSERT ON tickreqs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.codeyear = YEAR(NOW())
  SET NEW.requestcode = (SELECT IFNULL( MAX(requestcode) , 0 ) + 1 FROM tickreqs WHERE codeyear=YEAR(NOW()))
END`

Comment: I've got it. I forgot ; sign and somehow the trigger created. Thank a lot Jorge. I will try to format my number and post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will give you code as 20170001 20170002 and so on.

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER GenRequestCode BEFORE INSERT ON tickreqs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_NumberOfRowsToday BIGINT;
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_NumberOfRowsToday FROM tickreqs WHERE YEAR(createdate) = YEAR(NOW());
   SET NEW.requestcode = concat(YEAR(Now()), RIGHT(CONCAT('0000', 
CONVERt(v_NumberOfRowsToday + 1, CHAR)), 4));
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code get the job done but maybe little tweak.

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER GenRequestCode BEFORE INSERT ON tickreqs FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.codeyear = YEAR(NOW());
  SET NEW.requestcode = (SELECT IFNULL( MAX(requestcode) , 0 ) + 1 FROM tickreqs WHERE codeyear=YEAR(NOW()));
END
```