# MySQL Field AUTO_INCREMENT according to YEAR

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have a table for bills and I need to create the ID field (Primary Key) with this format:

```
YYYYXXXX -> YEAR+INT(4) Auto_increment
```

For example: `20150000`, `20150001`, ...., `20159999`

And it should close at the end of the year and start again at zero in the next year: `20160000`, `20160001`, ...
with the posibility to change it manually too.

Maybe some of you could help me as I'm new to mysql and php.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "possibility to change it manually" ? By the way: you are only searching a solution for mysql because php is not involved in setting the primary key.

Comment: No. You don't need auto_increment to do that. Reason is very simple - it exists only so a row in the database can have something unique about it. It does not carry data about the year, your name or whatever you might think it should. It's one and only job is to give a unique number to the row.  It is also used for a lot of internal optimizing - so you must never touch it. All what I wrote means that you are looking at the wrong column for the task. Instead of saving two pieces of data into 1 column, simply make 2 columns. When you pull the data out, glue the auto_increment with the date. Easy.

Answer (score -1):

You need to update auto increment counter to achieve this. Sample code attached.

```
ALTER TABLE  `TABLE_NAME` AUTO_INCREMENT =2015000;
```

However you need to make sure to update this once one the beginning of 2016 again like :  ALTER TABLE  `TABLE_NAME` AUTO_INCREMENT =2016000;

You can make a CRON job & add this conditional logic there :

```
alter.php:
<?php
 $conn = mysql_connect(.....);
 $selDb = mysql_select_db(....);
 $sql = 'ALTER TABLE  `TABLE_NAME` AUTO_INCREMENT ='.date("Y").'000';
 mysql_execute($sql);
?>

CRON:
1 1 1 1  * php alter.php
```