# MYSQL autoincrement with date day year

Tags: mysql

I am encountering this kind of advance SQL coding task like generating an auto-increment primary key ID that consists of a year day date, a special char and a sequential series no.

```
20201323 001
20201324 002
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you want the primary key to be `20201323 001`, like including a whitespace space character?

Comment: make generated column(if your version supports it) which uses the auto__increment id

Comment: how about an auto increment if its not a primarty key

Answer (score 0):

if you create primary key rows ,
you make composite primary key

```
/*you want　variable name */
PRIMARY KEY(date, id)
```

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(date, %Y%m%d) /*20201023*/
```