# JdbcBatchItemWriter processing on tables having FK relation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement to insert data into two tables using JdbcBatchItemWriter.

I have two tables TABLE_A, TABLE_B.

TABLE_B is child of TABLE_A with Foreign Key Relation. I am successful on inserting data using this batch writer to TABLE_A.

However, due to FK constraint, I cannot know the FK value to insert in TABLE_B.

Please let me know if there is a way to get the primary key values for the records inserted in TABLE_A during the process so that I can build a object and itemwrite into TABLE_B.

Comment: Additionally I wanted to mention that, the PK for TABLE_A is a sequence which generates automatically. Hence, even when I try to use the CompositeItemWriter, I cannot reuse the Object for next table writers. 

However, I tried to insert data for TABLE_A initially using simpleJdbcInsert and get the PK value and then use JDBCBatchWriter to write other tables. 

This approach seems to be more time consuming which hits the performance when there are huge records. 

Appreciate if any thoughts on this.

Comment: I am implementing the same thing and stuck with the same situation have you find any way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure `JdbcBatchItemWriter` out of the box will give you the capability as it uses the `batchUpdate` operation which doesn't give you back the generated primary key but the affected row count instead.

you may have to implement your own writer in which case have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc) to provide insight on generally retrieving generated ids from java sql.

Comment: Thank you. Currently I am using my query as

INSERT INTO TEST_A(TESTA.nextval,NAME)

The time take for inserting records when used this way is less compare to when I write my custom writer. So would there be a chance to get use this sequence id to child tables. Please advise.

Comment: this approach 'leaves' the id (TESTA.nextval) inside the database realm and, as such, unaccessible to the application tier. if using the inser from dual (nextval) you may want to look at the second table being populated with 'insert into ... select from' using the 'name' column as your 'where' criteria

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a DAO extending JdbcTemplate to do this.

I had problem using SimpleJdbcInsert (DB2 drvier problem!!) in my project, so i finally used this code!!

You can implement your own InsertAndReturnKey method like this:

```
public Number insertAndReturnKey(final Domain param) {


    final String INSERT_SQL = "insert INTO " + DomainEnum.TABLE_NAME.value() + 
    " (" + DomainEnum.F1.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F2.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F3.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F4.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F5.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F6.value() + ","
    + DomainEnum.F7.value() + ") values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    log.info(INSERT_SQL);

    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    this.update(
        new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps =
                    connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {SommaireReglementMetaData.ID.value()});
                ps.setString(1, param.getF1());
                ps.setString(2, param.getF2());
                ps.setLong(3, param.getF3());
                ps.setTimestamp(4, param.getF4());
                ps.setString(5, param.getF5());
                ps.setTimestamp(6, param.getF6());
                ps.setTimestamp(7, param.getF7());

                return ps;
            }
        },
        keyHolder);



    return keyHolder.getKey();
}
```

So basicaly, you could use this method to insert your parent. then use the batchUpdate to insert all the childs.

Question:  Do you have a lots of TABLE_A (parents) or just 1 and lots of TABLE_B records?

Comment: I have one record in TABLE_A which is Parent Table and many records in TABLE_B (child tables). There are many child tables to it like TABLE_C, TABLE_D which has FK relation ship with TABLE_A.

Comment: How did you get Spring Batch to then use the DAO as a writer?

Comment: @BrianC, you only autowire it in your defined writer.

Comment: Hi @Cygnusx1
May I know how do you guys solve this if it is the problem eg below? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58299578/compositeitemwriter-by-using-delegates-insertjdbcbatchitemwriter-into-2-tables