# How to get the Generated insert ID in JDBC?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

My source code has the following structure:

**SourceFolder**
  AddProduct.jsp
**Source Packages**
-**Controller**(Servlets)
  SaveProduct.java
-**Model**(Db Operations)
  ProductDbOperations.java

I am inserting a new product into the product table and at the same time I am inserting an entry into **product_collection** table (product_id | collection_id).

To insert an entry into the **product_collection** table i need to get generated id from **product** table. After that a new entry is inserted into the **product_collection** table.

Also, I am not using any Framework and am using **Netbeans 7.3.**

**Problem:**

A new entry is inserted into the product table with this piece of code

**IN: ProductDbOperations.java**

```
try
{
    this.initConnection(); // Db connection 
    pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product values('"+name+"', "+quantity+", "+price+")");
    rs = pst.executeUpdate();
}
catch(SQLException ex)
{   

}
```

I Also used the solution at following link which doesn't works for me.
I didn't got any SQL exception

[How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

so help me find out why this code not working for me .
Thanks a million.

Comment: How do you know you don't get an SQLException, your catch block is empty? Also did you try the getGeneratedKeys() method?

Comment: What does "doesn't work for me" mean? What happens? At least print the stack trace in your catch block: `catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: @Kayaman Actually 
The code is very large so let me explain ..
i m using a status variable of type String to get exception as string and function return a string like
status = ex.toString();

after try catch block
return status;

Comment: Also System.out.println(); is not displaying anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all drivers support the version of `getGeneratedKeys()` as shown in the linked answer. But when preparing the statement, you can also pass the list of columns that should be returned instead of the "flag" `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` (and passing the column names works more reliably in my experience)

Additionally: as javaBeginner pointed out correctly, your usage of a prepared statement is wrong. The way you do it, will still leave you wide open to SQL injection.

```
// run the INSERT
String sql = "INSERT INTO product values(?,?,?)";
pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql, new String[] {"PRODUCT_ID"} );
pst.setString(1, name);
pst.setInt(2, quantity);
pst.setInt(3, price);
pst.executeUpdate();

// now get the ID:
ResultSet rs = pst.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) {
   long productId = rs.getLong(1);
}
```

Note that the column name passed to the call is case-sensitive. For Oracle the column names are usually uppercase. If you are using e.g. Postgres you would most probably need to pass `new String[] {"product_id"}`

Comment: Please explain why you used this
new String[] {"PRODUCT_ID"} 
The array of String

Comment: pls tell me why System.out.println(); not working for me. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are using is not the proper way of using preparedstatement

use the following way

```
    pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO product values(?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1,name);
pst.setInt(2,quantity);
pst.setInt(3,price);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: @javaBegginer 
I need the generated id from the product table.

Comment: While that is a very good advice it does not cover the real problem: how to get the generated key.

Comment: Can you tell me why using (?,?,?) for values is good for inserting or updating.

Comment: @Surinderツ It prevents SQL injection and typos for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to retrieve the key inserted by SQL. You can do it by:
Using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` in your previous insert and get the key which can be used in further insert

e.g:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Table (Col2, Col3) VALUES ('S', 50)";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
int count = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Comment: What does "SQL u" mean?

Comment: Just a typo mistake......
Yes there is a way to retrieve the key inserted by SQL ,u can do it by.....

Comment: I have edited your answer, please use actual words and do not abbreviate to single letters like u (you) and b (be), it makes your answer harder to read.