# Inserting one table's primary key into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, `Appointment` and `AppointmentDetails`.

`Appointment` table has two columns `AppId` and `CusId`.

`AppointmentDetail` table has `AppId`, `ApDay`, `Intime`, `OutTime`, `EmpId`.

`Appointment` table has `AppId` as its primary key, and it is set to auto increment.
`AppointmentDetails` table has primary key on `(AppId, ApDay)`.

My problem how get and insert the primary key of the `Appointment` table to `AppointmentDetails` table when I am inserting data into `Appointment` table???

Comment: Some comments - Appointment has a 't' in it. Tables can't have two primary keys - they can have a single primary key that contains two columns though.

Comment: I've given you an answer below, but actually would have been better asking for clarification as to how you are inserting etc. Including code examples is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method of doing it (with corrected spellings for table names though I accept these are sometimes beyond your control):

```
DECLARE @insertedId INT;
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO Appointment(CusId) VALUES(@cusId);
    SET @insertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
COMMIT

BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO
        AppointmentDetails
    SELECT
        AppId = @insertedId 
        ,ApDay = @apDay
        ,Intime = @inTime
        ,OutTime = @outTime
        ,EmpId = @empId
    FROM
        Appointment
COMMIT
```

Alternatively you could use a [trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), but they're just evil!

Answer (score 0):

I think they asking how can they return the new key that was generated to then insert it into the details table.

Check this post out if using JDBC but the idea is the same for all languages: [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)