# MSSQL - fetch Auto increment column value and save it in a another column

Tags: jdbc, auto-increment, mssql-jdbc

This is Regarding MSSQL auto increment feature and i have following table created

```
CREATE TABLE Order(
[order_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[original_order_id] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

In here i have a situation where i need to insert the auto generated value for original_id to original_order_id.

After googling few minutes following thing and it works fine for me

```
insert into Order values('Vegitable Order', IDENT_CURRENT('Order'))
```

I am using java application spring JDBC templates to execute the quires. can there be any issues? specially in multi threaded environment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `IDENT_CURRENT` is not a good idea. If there are concurrent transactions, the returned value might not be **your** last inserted id, but the last inserted id of **another** transaction!

Use the JDBC `getGeneratedKey` facility to retrieve the generated id of the first `INSERT` and use the retrieved value in the second `INSERT`, or use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the second `INSERT`. With `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` be sure that you are executing both statements in the same transaction.

See also: [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Comment: Hello Mark, Thank you very much for your answer. Here i can not use getGeneratedKey, because there are no 2 inserts. i want to save this auto generated value in to some other column in a same table. If i use  getGeneratedKeys i need to do a separate update on same table to update that column. Please let me know your thoughts

Comment: @keth I somehow missed that. Why would you want to save the identity column in a different column of the same table? That is unnecessary duplication of information; simply disallow changes of the identity column.