# execute multiple commands in java statement

Tags: java, mysql

Trying to execute an insert then get the last id value but I get that the select statement fails, however it works when I throw it into mysql workbench it works fine.  What is the java code failing?

```
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Statement
import java.sql.ResultSet
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String user = "root"
String password = "password"
Connection connection = null;
try {
    System.out.println("Connecting database...");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table_listnames (name) VALUES ('alex'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId;");
    while (rs.next()) {
        String lastId = rs.getString("lastId");
        println(lastId)
    }
    println("closing now")
    stmt.close()
    connection.close() 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
} finally {
    System.out.println("Closing the connection.");
    if (connection != null) try { 
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}
```

Comment: Bigger picture solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

An exececuteUpdate whill never return a ResultSet. See:

```
int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

You have to query for your new record.
You can try: getGeneratedKeys

But it's so long time ago I used plain java.sql i doesn't know how we handelt that.
Why u doesn't use something like hibernate. An inserted entity wil automaticly get his id set after transaction end.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is your problem:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table_listnames (name) VALUES ('alex'); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lastId;");
```

Your `SELECT` statement isn't an update.  But the JDBC call you're making is to do an UPDATE.

Split it into two calls.  Do the `SELECT` separately.

And don't forget to close your `ResultSet` objects (perhaps in the finally block).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote in a DAO to add a word with a wordID into a database table using JDBC it illustrates how to add a row into a table get the generated key. The first column in the word table is an INT (which gets autogenerated by the database when null), the second column is a VARCHAR containing the supplied word. The Word class (not shown) is just a trivial class to encapsulate the wordID integer and a String with getters and setters.

Although it is a little more complex than your question as it contains JNDI and prepared statements as well, this code should get you started.

`/** Attempts to add a Word. Returning a clone of the word including the wordID on success */
    static final Word createWord(final Word word) throws Exception
    {

        InitialContext initialContext = null;
        DataSource ds = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null; 
        ResultSet rs = null;`

```
    try{
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyDatabase" );
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        if(word.getWordID() == 0)
        {
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO words VALUES(?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);         //wordID
            stmt.setString(2, word.getText());

            // execute the insert and get the new wordID
            int rowsAdded = stmt.executeUpdate();       
            if(rowsAdded == 0)return null;              
            Integer key = null;
            rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
            if(rs.next()){key = new Integer(rs.getInt("GENERATED_KEY"));}
            rs.close();

            // clone the word but add in the word id
            Word retval = new Word(word.getText());
            retval.setWordID(key);
            return retval;
        }
        return null;    
    }
    catch(NamingException e)
    {           
        throw new Exception("WordDAO: failed to obtain DataSource", e);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(Log.isLogError())Log.error("WordDAO: SQLException" + e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Always make sure result sets and statements are closed and the connection is returned to the pool
        if (rs != null){try{rs.close();}catch (SQLException e){}rs = null;}
        if (stmt != null){try{stmt.close();}catch(SQLException e){}stmt = null;}
        if (conn != null){try {conn.close();}catch(SQLException e){}conn = null;}
    }
}
```