# getInt method isn't returning a value from a database table

Tags: java, jdbc, plsql

I have a oracle table defined like this:

```
create table image_table_test (id number primary key, image ordsys.ordimage);
```

when I try to select maximum ID value in that table and return it in java variable, using the code below, it returns a zero value, but the value in a table is set to 1. the `rsx.getInt("ID");` method isn't returning an integer value from a table.

my table When I execute `SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM image_table_test;`:

```
ID
1
```

my java code:

```
Statement stmt;

try{
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    String maxIdStr = "";
    int maxIdNum = 0;

    String maxIdSQL = "SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM image_table_test";                
    ResultSet rsx = stmt.executeQuery(maxIdSQL);

    while(rsx.next()){
        maxIdNum = rsx.getInt("ID"); // Here the value is passed as 0
    }

    maxIdNum = maxIdNum + 1;
    maxIdStr = Integer.toString(maxIdNum);

    System.out.println(maxIdStr);
    rsx.close();
    stmt.close();
```

I would appreciate your help if you know why is this happening?

Comment: Presumably the query fails for some reason and you are getting the default value that you set it to when you declare the variable.

Comment: I have declared a try and catch block, and it isn't throwing an exception. So i presume the query is not failing. The same query executes just fine on server directly.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch the last inserted id from the database? If yes then, transactionally, this is not the correct way to do so. Please [see](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1915166/1391249).

Comment: Please check to be sure that your Java code is connecting to the expected database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is ok, but I don't trust in your query result.

Try setting a negative value on maxIdNum to see if your are getting results from your query.

```
int maxIdNum = -1;
```

Another test you can do is replacing `rsx.getInt("ID");` by `rs.getString("ID");` to know if the result is a string it will fail in case of int so will help you to isolate the problem.

Another you can do is to set a query with a hardcoded result to know if there is another problem:

```
select 1 as ID from dual
```

Comment: If i set the variable to -1 it still returns 0.

Comment: @eror404 I updated the answer. Add the query I added to check if that works. That will help you to know what the problem is

Comment: this returns one it must be the query but i can't see what is wrong with it. tnx

Comment: For some reason capital letters does not work in java. If i execute it in lowercase: select max(ID) as ID from image_table_test, then it works. Opposed to SELECT MAX(ID) as ID FROM image_table_test;

Comment: I wasted 3 hours on that. that is just plain stupid.

Comment: @eror404 the good news is that you solved it. About the lowercase, maybe you have an old driver. Btw, it is always useful to have a hardcoded value to mock results.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not fetching the ID column, I'd change it to :

```
maxIdNum = rsx.getInt(1);
```

instead of :

```
maxIdNum = rsx.getInt("ID");
```

I'd also change the query to :

```
String maxIdSQL = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM image_table_test";
```

Comment: I did try this and it still returns 0.