# How to find last entry to a Database

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am inserting a row using

```
String sql="insert into OCS_TBL_DOCTOR values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, doctor.getDoctorID());
        ps.setString(2, doctor.getDoctorName());
        ps.setString(3, doctor.getDateOfBirth());
        ps.setString(4, doctor.getDateOfJoining());
        ps.setString(5, doctor.getGender());
        ps.setString(6, doctor.getQualification());
        ps.setString(7, doctor.getSpecialization());
        ps.setInt(8, doctor.getYearsOfExperience());
        ps.setString(9, doctor.getStreet());
        ps.setString(10, doctor.getLocation());
        ps.setString(11, doctor.getCity());
        ps.setString(12, doctor.getState());
        ps.setString(13, doctor.getPincode());
        ps.setString(14, doctor.getContactNo());
        ps.setString(15, doctor.getEmaiID());
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I want to know how will I get that last entry that I have just inserted. Here DoctorID is the primary key.

Comment: Make a select on `id` equal to whatever you pass as `doctor.getDoctorId`?..

Comment: select the record back out again?

Comment: Since you're setting the PK explicitly, then you *already know* its value!  If, on the other hand (and contrary to the code you have shown), you are *not* setting an explicit value for `DoctorID` and it happens to be an integer column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, you can obtain the "last insert id" from Java—see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/623041.

Comment: I am using the AUTO_INCREMENT for DoctorID. what I am sending through the query is null value so that whenever the database executes the query, the null value is encountered, and the DoctorID is configured automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql="select * fom OCS_TBL_DOCTOR WHERE doctor_id_in_database="+doctor.getDoctorID();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

**Firstly** as it is an insert statement and you are specifying the DoctorID to be persisted, you can always requery on that field **or** you can create an index for DoctorID and get the maximum.

**Secondly**, you can create another column which stores created/modified date and let the database stamp system time to it. Once the insert is done, you can query based on this column and add order by desc.

Comment: Actually I am Using an auto increment for DoctorID. The Value that i am sending through the query is null. Therefore i wont be knowing that DoctorID

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the time stamp? I guess that might do the trick

Comment: @Swagato, If you add a new column, in the database which stores date and while populating each row, use system date to be stored in that column. this would assist us in ordering this column in descending order so as to retrieve the most recent record.