# Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()

Tags: java, jdbc

I am injecting my database with the JSON file and am trying to get the `route_id` from the `routes` table after inserting the route and the direction (Also of the inserted direction and route record). I have changed `prep.executeUpdate()` to `prep.executeQuery()` but I am getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)

**Code:**

```
            DatabaseMetaData dbm = con.getMetaData();

            ResultSet routesTables = dbm.getTables(null, null, "routes", null);

            if (routesTables.next()) {

                PreparedStatement prep = con
                        .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO routes(direction, route)"
                                + "VALUES( ?, ?)");

                prep.setString(1, direction);
                prep.setInt(2, route);

                ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();


            }
```

How can I get the route_id in this case `ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();`? Currently I am getting the error above.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call  `prep.executeUpdate();` for insert statement.
Not `ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();`. `prep.executeQuery();` is only for select queries.

Comment: And then I can get the `route_id` like this `int rs = prep.executeUpdate();`?

Comment: @light No you get the `effected rows` in rs

Comment: If you need the id see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc