# MySql How Insert Data in different tables using same ID

Tags: java, mysql

im a pretty new self student and i am trying to insert Data in different tables but using same ID like that and for the tab 3 set a default Date like 2000/01/01:
My tables are like:

tab1
Id1
varchardate1

tab2
ID
Id1
varchardate2

tab3
ID
Id1
datetime

Im using that code to insert Data in the tab1:

```
String sub1 = "Insert Into tab1 (`varchardate1`) values "
                    + "(" + jTextField1.getText() + "')";
            System.out.println(sub1);
```

Now i can do the same but i want to save that Id1 and use it for the other 2 tables and for tab3 i want to set that default datetime 2000/01/01.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: My bad. I posted a PHP solution for a Java question. You might wanna look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood: 
**import  java.sql.*;**

```
  static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
  static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";
  String txtfld =  jtextField.getText();

try{
      // register the JDBC driver
     Class.forname("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
    String query = "INSERT INTO tab1(varchardate1) VALUES(?)";    
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.preparedStatement(query);
    // set prepared statements in the order you have the columns
    stmt.setString(1,txtfld);
    stmt.executeUpdate();

   String query2 = "SELECT id FROM tab1 WHERE varchardate1 = ?";
   PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.preparedStatement(query2);
   stmt.setString(1, txtfld );
   ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query2);

   int  tab1Id = result.getInt('id');

   //at this point just insert the next
   // to values with the `id` extracted from first insertion

} catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {

        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
        }

        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }

    }
```

1. use [Prepared Statements](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/) for security purposes when inserting data into a  database
2. Best practice to learn a `persistance framework` like [Hibernate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/) or [EJB](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ejb/) which  uses `JPA`

Comment: And if my Id1 in the first tab is the highest Id1 (already present in my tab1) +1 how should be the query? like that: ` String sql = "select Id1 from tab1 order by ID desc "; `

Comment: @user2853957, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: I still don't understand. if you speak spanish, please do so, I speak it also. maybe this way we can understand each other better.

Comment: but in your query,  there should  be  a `UNIQUE ID `  in every table. so your  resultset   will only  have  ONE  result, thus  the  `ORDER BY ID DESC`  would be unnecessary.

Comment: sorry i do not speak spanish, but thanks to you it works.

Comment: @user2853957, glad to help, make sure to check the answer if it was the correct one.