# Retrieve non-sequence value on insert using Java

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, h2

I have created a Table `TEST_DETAIL` as

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DETAIL(
  TEST_KEY BIGINT DEFAULT CAST(FORMATDATETIME(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSSSSS') AS BIGINT) PRIMARY KEY,
  TEST_NO BIGINT DEFAULT TEST_NO_SEQ.NEXTVAL,NAME VARCHAR(40),AGE DECIMAL(5,2),GENDER CHAR(1),ADDRESS VARCHAR(250), MOBILE_NO VARCHAR(20),DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);
```

I am inserting records into table though `jdbc`.On insertion I have to retrieve `TEST_KEY & TEST_NO`.I am able to retrieve `TEST_NO` as it is a sequence using following logic, as explained  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/1101032)

```
    int insertedRow=statement.executeUpdate(sSql);          
        if (insertedRow == 0) {
            throw new SQLException("Failed!!");
        }           
        ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()){             
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));              
        }
```

How to retrieve `TEST_KEY` which is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: what do you mean by that? 
you can do `rs.getTimeStamp()`

Comment: @karthik `The method getTimeStamp() is undefined for the type ResultSet` and `rs` has only `generatedKeys` which here is `TEST_NO` not `TEST_KEY`

Comment: @karthik `rs` has only `generatedKeys` which here is `TEST_NO` not `TEST_KEY`

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain a bit clearly??

Comment: @karthik what is not clear to you here? I have provided tables details and what I am looking for

Comment: what is your query? Without that how would somebody know what is coming in your resultset?

Comment: @karthik please check now, I have updated, here `sSql` is an `insert` query

Answer (score 0):

Try using an explicit definition of the auto generated keys you want to get back:

```
int insertedRow = statement.executeUpdate(sSQL, new String[]{"TEST_KEY", "TEST_NO"});
```

Here are Javadocs for the method:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29