# Use Auto incremented unique id primary key as foreign key in another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `primary_details` which has the the following fields

`uid` ---> primary key & Auto incremented & unique 
`name`
`age`

I have another table `cust_info` with the following fields

`uid` ---> foreign key of primary key in `primary_details` table & not unique 
`score`
`comments`

Now the question is when ever I insert a row in `primary_details` table it automatically inserts the value in `uid` column and it auto increments on all subsequent new rows which is perfect. However now I want the `uid` in `cust_info` table to also have the same `uid` value as in the `primary_details` table when ever I write a row in the `primary_details` table

For Eg:

In `primary_details` table if I insert the following row

```
uid    name   age   
1      Mark   25
```

Now if I insert a record in secondary table right after the above one it should also get the `uid` 1

I'm using Java to write the tables. In java I can easily generate a `uid` and insert it into the table but I wanna use the unique ID and auto increment feature in MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Insert the row in the parent table `primary_details`.
2. Then, retrieve the generated uid with the method you want : [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)
3. Insert in the child table `cust_info` using the previously generated uid.

On a side note, your child table should have its own uid and a different field for the foreign key.

Example:

**Customer**
uid ---> primary key auto incremented
name
age

**CustomerDetails**
uid ---> primary key auto incremented
customer_id---> foreign key on Customer table
score
comments

Comment: Thanks. perfect. This is exactly what I needed.