# I can't get the getGeneratedKeys with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I'm blocked on a stupid problem in one of my functions.
I want to get the generatedKey of one of my Sql query. I can't and i don't understand why. The problem is that `resultSet.next()` it return false even if the line have been inserted when I check the data in the table.

Here is my code :

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.application (nom,criticite,autorise) VALUES ('"+nom+"','"+criticite+"','"+false+"');");

 ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
 resultSet.next();
```

---

Solution : Add `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.application (nom,criticite,autorise) VALUES ('"+nom+"','"+criticite+"','"+false+"');", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
resultSet.next();
```

Comment: Try adding `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as the second argument to the `.executeUpdate` method call (after the SQL statement).

Comment: oh my god ... It worked thank you so much !

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and even accept it.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works. `INSERT INTO calamar.calamar.application` is invalid for Postgres because you can't have a three part identifier there. Are you _sure_ you are using Postgres? Also: please use a `PreparedStatement` instead http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'm using it and that it works.
Isn't i should do : db.schema.table ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)