# Trying to insert ID and getting "cannot accept a NULL value"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, insert, auto-generate

I am trying to insert record in Derby database with auto generated key and I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'CUSTOMERID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at jakub.ordereditor.OrderEditorMain.create(OrderEditorMain.java:54)
>       at jakub.ordereditor.OrderEditorMain.main(OrderEditorMain.java:39)
>   Caused by: ERROR 23502: Column 'CUSTOMERID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientStatement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
>       ... 3 more

I followed this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197 and many others.
My piece of code:

```
package jan.ordereditor;

import jan.ordereditor.customer.entity.Customer;
import jan.ordereditor.customer.entity.CustomerName;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class OrderEditorMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        CustomerName customerFullName = new CustomerName();
        customerFullName.setCustomerFirstName("John");
        customerFullName.setCustomerSurname("Doe");

        customer.setCustomerFullName(customerFullName);

        create(customer);

    }

    public static void create(Customer customer) throws SQLException {
        String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO customer (customerFirstName, customerSurname) VALUES (?,?)";
        try (
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/OrderEditor");
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT,
                        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);) {
            CustomerName customerFullName = customer.getCustomerFullName();
            statement.setString(1, customerFullName.getCustomerFirstName());
            statement.setString(2, customerFullName.getCustomerSurname());


            int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();

            if (affectedRows == 0) {
                throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no rows affected.");
            }

            try (ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                if (generatedKeys.next()) {
                    customer.setCustomerId(generatedKeys.getInt(1));
                } else {
                    throw new SQLException("Creating user failed, no ID obtained.");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and my DB id in database Derby:

[image]

Comment: Make you id to Auto_increment or add it to the insert statement

Comment: make your id to auto_increment and not null.

Comment: `id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)` is this statement present in your DDL?

Comment: @Imran : No, I did not. I have just created table with adding column feature and I have not filled constraints. Now it works nice. I have followed SQL constraints you mentioned.

Comment: And now I am wondering why does it work without defying generatedKeys?

Comment: Sorry, I have found it out. It will work without defying generatedKeys, but If I create new record I will get "id" in my table 0 ("null"). If I implement generatedKeys I will get next id (generated automatically by my DB).

Answer (score 2):

You need to **remove** and **readd** the `customerid` column in your table as an identity column.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName add customerid int identity(1,1)
```

Starting with 1, On every insert, value will be incremented by 1.