# jruby jdbc how to get id of inserted row

Tags: ruby, odbc, jruby

I have insert query that works, but I can't get ID of created row in return. How can I achieve that? having this:

```
conn = Java::JavaSql::DriverManager.getConnection(url)
st = conn.create_statement
rs = st.execute_update(query)
```

How can I get id?

Answer (score 1):

more of a JDBC question that depends on the DB/driver used.

generally `st.generated_keys` gives you a result set of the IDs

also read: [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)