# Get the inserted id of the record before or after execute the insert statement in sql

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have this method in my DAO class to insert record to a table called idea this is my method:

```
    public long  addIdea(AddIdeaDto addIdeaDto, int userId) {

    Connection connection = null;

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnection();



        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO IDEA ( IDEA.I_ID,IDEA.I_NO,IDEA.I_APPROVER_NAME_CODE, IDEA.I_TITLE,IDEA.I_DESCRIPITION, IDEA.I_CREATED_DATE,IDEA.I_STATUS_CODE, "
                        + "IDEA.I_IS_CODE, IDEA.I_CONTRIBUTION_CODE, IDEA.I_POSITIVE_IMPACT, IDEA.I_SECOND_MEMBER_ID,IDEA.I_THIRD_MEMBER_ID,IDEA.I_FOURTH_MEMBER_ID,"
                        + "IDEA.I_FIFTH_MEMBER_ID, IDEA.I_POINTS,IDEA.I_CREATED_USER_ID)"
                        + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


        preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT IDEA_SEQ.nextval FROM DUAL");

        // Set parameters
        preparedStatement.setObject(1, Types.NUMERIC);
        preparedStatement.setObject(2, Types.NUMERIC);

        preparedStatement.setObject(3, addIdeaDto.getApproverNameCode());

        preparedStatement.setString(4, addIdeaDto.getTitle());

        preparedStatement.setString(5, addIdeaDto.getDescription());
        preparedStatement.setDate(6, addIdeaDto.getCreatedDate() == null ? null
                : new java.sql.Date(addIdeaDto.getCreatedDate().getTime()));

        preparedStatement.setObject(7, addIdeaDto.getStatusCode());
        preparedStatement.setObject(8, addIdeaDto.getIsNewCode());

        preparedStatement.setObject(9, addIdeaDto.getContributionCode());

        preparedStatement.setString(10, addIdeaDto.getPositiveImpact());
        preparedStatement.setObject(11, addIdeaDto.getSecondMemberName());
        preparedStatement.setObject(12, addIdeaDto.getThirdMemberName());
        preparedStatement.setObject(13, addIdeaDto.getFourthMemberName());
        preparedStatement.setObject(14, addIdeaDto.getFifthMemberName());

        preparedStatement.setObject(15, addIdeaDto.getPoints());
        preparedStatement.setInt(16, userId);

        preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        return addIdeaDto.getIdeaId();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

actually what I want is after or before the insert statement I want to get the id (IDEA_SEQ.nextval) and save it in a value in order to use it as an input to insert in anther table.

For example, I insert this record : id = 1 , no = 1, approver code = 2, title = 'test'.............

I want this value id = 1 to use it in order to insert in table A, A_id = 33, IDEA.I_ID = 1, A_name ='testing'

how i can achieve it in properer way?

I update the code based on the comments that i receive but I did not achieve it

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Usually ID that need to be reuse can be handle using a previous and separate SQL query

```
 previousPreparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
            "select IDEA_SEQ.nextval as nextval from dual");
```

Result saved as a `int` or `String` parameter according to column (`number` or `varchar`) which is passed to the existing insert statement:

```
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Notice also an [answer from DBA forum](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27180/using-the-same-sequence-twice-in-a-pl-sql-statement)

> you won't be able to use plain SQL to overcome this limitation: you will need some PL/SQL

Comment: It will be like : String id = "select IDEA_SEQ.nextval as nextval from dual " and preparedStatement.setObject(1, id);

Comment: Thank you, and when i set the parameter I will set it as string

Comment: I will have to statements select and insert

Comment: @wadhaalketbi or int, according to oracle column varchar or number

Comment: both is int but I will save the first statement (select) as int then when I will set the parameter of second statement I will put this variable ?

Comment: @wadhaalketbi yes, put the variable twice index 1 and 2

Comment: I will try it if it will work with, but this is what I want

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: @wadhaalketbi you should you `setInt` instead of `setObject(1, Types.NUMERIC)`

Comment: it will be like setInt(1, Types.NUMERIC)??? And is right to have to prepare statements??

Comment: @wadhaalketbi `setInt(1, yourId)` , `yourId` should be returned from the new SQL to get the nextval

Comment: so there is ResultSet, the 2 prepare statements it will be in the same method (addIdea) and the ResultSet of the Select statment, it will be the parameter of the I_ID ??

Answer (score 0):

A better way to handle this is the [`RETURNING INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause, which uses a single, atomic statement:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, col1, col2)
VALUES ( seq_id.nextval, c1, c2 )
RETURNING id INTO myval;
```

Comment: I add returning to my query it give me missing keyword

Comment: `returning into` can only be used inside a PL/SQL block, not in a SQL query.

Comment: I would argue that the best way to handle this is to turn it into a function that returns the new id. See #SmartDB on Twitter. Stop writing SQL! (See Feuerstein)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()` to obtain the generated value. There is no need to use a separate statement:

You also can't prefix column names with the table name in list of columns of an `INSERT` statement.

```
String insert = 
     "INSERT INTO IDEA ( I_ID,I_NO,I_APPROVER_NAME_CODE, I_TITLE,I_DESCRIPITION, I_CREATED_DATE,I_STATUS_CODE, "
   + "I_IS_CODE, I_CONTRIBUTION_CODE, I_POSITIVE_IMPACT, I_SECOND_MEMBER_ID,I_THIRD_MEMBER_ID,I_FOURTH_MEMBER_ID,"
   + "I_FIFTH_MEMBER_ID, I_POINTS,I_CREATED_USER_ID)"
   + " VALUES (idea_seq.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql, new String[] {"I_ID"});
preparedStatement.setInt(1, ???); // don't know where the value for I_NO comes from
preparedStatement.setString(2, addIdeaDto.getApproverNameCode());
preparedStatement.setString(3, addIdeaDto.getTitle());
... other parameters
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
long newId = -1;

if (rs.next()) {
  newId = rs.getLong("I_ID");
}

... use the NewId ...
```

The parameter `new String[] {"I_ID"}` for the `prepareStatement()` call tells the JDBC driver to return the generated value for that column. That value can be retrieved through `getGeneratedKeys()` which returns a ResultSet that contains one row for each inserted row (so exactly one in this case). The ID value can then be extracted from the ResultSet using the the usual `getLong()` (or `getInt()`) methods.