# How to get last insert in Java Derby

Tags: java, sql, database, derby

I am trying to get the last ID inserted on the Java Derby DataBase.

This is a little program that i did, but i think that could be better ways to do that:

```
    Query queryUsuarios = em.createNamedQuery("Usuario.findAll");
    List<Usuario> listUsuario = queryUsuarios.getResultList();
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < listUsuario.size(); i++) {
        Usuario verUsuario = em.find(Usuario.class, i);
        if(verUsuario != null) {
            System.out.println(i+")"+verUsuario.getNombres());
        }
    }System.out.println("The last ID is "+i);
```

The main question is, there is a better and more secure way to do this?. Because i think on this way i could get errors in the future...

Thank you!.

Comment: Use `Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/193453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `LIMIT` and `order by`.Check below:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `table_id` desc LIMIT 1;
```