# does TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE prevent inserting the same id twice with id = old_id + 1

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

My code is as follows:

- read max(id) from table A
- insert new row with new_id = max(id)+1 in table A
- insert multiple rows in another table B, with this new_id.

So if there are multiple users trying to do this operation at the same time, they can get the same max(id) and insert two rows with the same id. Can I use TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE to prevent this, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Don't generate IDs this way, use a sequence or an auto-increment column instead.

Comment: I can't use auto-increment I need that id in the next query, it's like inserting a new student then inserting his grades in another table with his id

Comment: You can, use the JDBC generated keys facility to retrieve the inserted id and use it for the next statement. See [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Comment: will this work on a multi-client server without causing problems?
and I still want to know  how to close the table until the row is inserted

Comment: Ids generated using identity columns or sequences are safe under concurrent access: they are outside of transaction control and will always emit a value one higher than the previously emitted value (even if that previous transactions was rolled back).

Comment: so if two transactions tried to get the max_id it will return two different values (t and t+1) ? 
thanks a lot, that's what I need

Comment: If you use a sequence or identity column, yes.