# PreparedStatement getMaxRows always returns 0

Tags: java, mysql, database

So i have a problem where i want to see how many rows there are in my database, after i've made an update. Im trying to use "GetMaxRows" but it always returns 0. i suspect that it is because i dont have a ResaultSet, but i can't get that when using PreparedStatement.executeUpdate()? Any suggestions or mistakes i've made?

```
protected void createOrder(Carport carport, Shed shed, User user){

    Logger.getLogger("web").log(Level.INFO, "");

    String sql = "insert into carport.order (length, width, material, userId, shedIncluded) values(?,?,?,?,?)";

    int shedIncluded = 1;
    if (shed == null) shedIncluded = 0;

    int maxRows = 0;

    try (Connection connection = connectionPool.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setInt(1, carport.getLength());
            ps.setInt(2, carport.getWidth());
            ps.setString(3,carport.getMaterial());
            ps.setInt(4,user.getUserId());
            ps.setInt(5,shedIncluded);
            int rowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
            int test = ps.getMaxRows();
            System.out.println(test);

            if(rowsAffected == 1){
                System.out.println("Carport data is saved");
            }
            else{
                throw new DatabaseException("Could not save Carport data");
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | DatabaseException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(shedIncluded == 1) createShedOrder(shed, maxRows);
}
```

Comment: 0 means that there is no upper limit set on the max rows **the ResultSet can contain**. You can set a limit with ``setMaxRows(int limit)``

Comment: The `getMaxRows` method simply does not do what you think it does. From its documentation: "Retrieves the maximum number of rows that a ResultSet object produced by this Statement object can contain. If this limit is exceeded, the excess rows are silently dropped. Returns:
    the current maximum number of rows for a ResultSet object produced by this Statement object; zero means there is no limit" - If you want to check how many rows already exist in your Database you need to do a query, like a simple `count (*) from carport.order` sql query or something similar.

Comment: Okay, i see. Then im using the wrong approach. How can i check what row the update is in my database? It should always be in the last spot and get an auto incremented ID.

Comment: Okay. So I have to go and do a query. hoped i could get around that. Thanks alot guys!

Comment: "How can i check what row the update is in my database?" <- But you are not doing an "update", you are doing an explicit "insert" query. That one will always insert as the name tells and not update an existing data. Checking if an "insert" query really inserts and doesn't update seems totally pointless to me.

Comment: If you want to get the generated ID(s) after an insert: [If it is an auto generated key, then you can use Statement#getGeneratedKeys() for this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915197/6073886)

Comment: THAT WORKED PERFECTLY! Exactly what i was after. Thanks alot for your help. :D