# RETURNING syntax in PostgreSQL doesn't return SERIAL type attribute in Java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert two records each to **event** table and **reminderinfo** table. First, the schemas are as follows:

#### Events table

```
                                            Table "public.events"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 event_id     | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('events_event_id_seq'::regclass)
 title        | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 participants | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 location     | character varying(20)       |           |          | 
 description  | character varying(255)      |           |          | 
 creator_id   | integer                     |           |          | 
 start_time   | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 end_time     | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (event_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "events_creator_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (creator_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "reminderinfo" CONSTRAINT "reminderinfo_event_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(event_id)
    TABLE "reminders" CONSTRAINT "reminders_event_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(event_id)
```

#### Reminderinfo table

```
                                 Table "public.reminderinfo"
   Column   |     Type      | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                  
------------+---------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------
 id         | integer       |           | not null | nextval('reminderinfo_id_seq'::regclass)
 event_id   | integer       |           |          | 
 time_frame | integer       |           |          | 
 interval_q | interval_enum |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "reminderinfo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "reminderinfo_event_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(event_id)
```

Because I want to insert them simultaneously while `event_id`(SERIAL type in PostgreSQL) of **reminderinfo** table references to `event_id` of **events** table, I tried to make INSERT query return event_id with **RETURNING** syntax.

```java
String SQL_INSERT1 = "INSERT INTO events (title, start_time, end_time, description, creator_id, location, participants) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING event_id;";
String SQL_INSERT2 = "INSERT INTO reminderinfo (event_id, time_frame, interval_q) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPasswd);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT1);
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT2);) {

    preparedStatement.setString(1, titleCreated);
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(startCreated).getTime()));
    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(endCreated).getTime()));
    preparedStatement.setString(4, descCreated);
    preparedStatement.setInt(5, creatorId);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, locationCreated);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, participantCreated);

    System.out.println(preparedStatement);
    ResultSet res = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    if (res.next()) {

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Event has been well created!", "Event created", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       System.out.println(String.format("res is %s", res.getInt(0)));
       int eventID = res.getInt(1);
```

But `res.getInt(1)` line raises `The column index is out of range: 0, number of columns: 1.` error. Event record is well inserted though.

I know the very dull solution - running `SELECT event_id FROM events WHERE ..` every time after inserting event record makes no problem, but I want fancy one!

ps. I've read answers in the question seemingly similar to mine, but they are in different situations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the insert ID in JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915166/how-to-get-the-insert-id-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`, which returns the generated key.

So remove the `RETURNING` clause from your query and add `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as a second parameter to your `prepareStatement()` function.

```
String SQL_INSERT1 = "INSERT INTO events (title, start_time, end_time, description, creator_id, location, participants) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT1, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Then get the key generated using `getGeneratedKeys()` function.

```
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    
ResultSet res = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (res.next()) {
   int eventID = res.getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I've just tried, but it raises ```ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.```.

Comment: @AhnJun-Yeong Sorry, change `res.next()`  to `if (res.next) { // here get evenID }`

Comment: The code doesn't get into if block - that is, it corresponds to else case (nothing in res). Any idea? Event_id in events is being generated automatically well :(

Comment: @AhnJun-Yeong try to change `executeUpdate()` with `execute()`

Comment: Sorry for my super late reply! It worked. I really appreciate your help with this! Have a nice day :)